# C# - stop function for TimeSpan in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I make a simple app with `TimeSpan` that repeat a song every 1 minute, that after I make it I can stop this song at this moment, but I can't stop timer by a button,

my code

```
public class AlertViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DispatcherTimer Timer { get; set; } = new DispatcherTimer();
    public List<int> TimeOuts { get; set; } = new List<int>();
    private int timeOut;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int selectedIndex;
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get {return selectedIndex;}
        set {selectedIndex = value; PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedIndex")); timeOut = TimeOuts[SelectedIndex];}
    }

    public List<Sound> Sounds { get; set; } = new List<Sound>();
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> TimeUP;

    List<TimeSpan> TName = new List<TimeSpan>();


    public AlertViewModel()
    {
        TimeOuts.Add(10);


        TimeOuts.Add(15);
        TimeOuts.Add(20);
        TimeOuts.Add(30);

        TimeOuts.Add(60);
        TimeOuts.Add(120);
        TimeOuts.Add(360);
        TimeOuts.Add(720);

        timeOut = TimeOuts[SelectedIndex];

        Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;

        Sounds.Add(new Sound("Sound 1", "ms-appx:///Assets/Audio/sound1.mp3"));
        Sounds.Add(new Sound("Sound 2", "ms-appx:///Assets/Audio/sound2.mp3"));
    }
    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        // int TimeOuts = this.TimeOuts[SelectedIndex];
        timeOut--;

        if (timeOut == 0)
        {
            TimeUP(this, new EventArgs());
            timeOut = TimeOuts[SelectedIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you tried to set `Timer.IsEnabled = false` when button is pressed and it doesn't work?

Comment: Did you try calling stop method on button click?

Comment: So show the button click event code please

Comment: when i use Timer.IsEnabled = false in button in MainPage.xaml.cs
said: 'Timer' dose not contain the definition for 'IsEnable'
so i can't do that

Comment: Use Command to add the click_event method in AlertViewModel

Answer (score 0):

> but I can't stop timer by a button

You can use DelegateCommand in your ViewModel and bind it to your stop button:

AlertViewModel:

```
public class AlertViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public RelayCommand CmdStop { get; set; }

    public AlertViewModel()
    {
         ...
         CmdStop = new RelayCommand(() => {
            if (Timer != null)
            {
                Timer.Stop();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

XAML:

```
...
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:AlertViewModel  />
</Page.DataContext>
...
<Button Name="btnStop" Command="{Binding CmdStop}">Click Me to Stop</Button>
```

Notes: I'm using RelayCommand in [MvvmLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/). You can use any framework as you like.